# How to change a timestamp using a value stored in other table

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
documents                                             
-------------------------------------------------------
id (int)                                              |
-------------------------------------------------------
created (timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)|



keywords                                              
-------------------------------------------------------
document_id (int, references documents.id)            |
-------------------------------------------------------
name (varchar)                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------
value (varchar)                                       |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Well, as keyword I have one called `Date` with values like `2013/22/10` (malformed).
`documents.created` was `datetime default 0` and because of that, it now holds `0000-00...` for all entries.

What I need to achieve, is to set the timestamp in `documents.created` to `2013-10-22 00:00:00` (based on the keyword `date` that all documents have).

So I see I would need some sort of function.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE ssp_docusearch_1.0.0_1.1.0 ()
  BEGIN
    SELECT
      k.name, k.value, d.id
    FROM
      keywords k 
    INNER JOIN
      documents d ON k.document_id = d.id
    WHERE k.name = 'Date'
  END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

But there I am stuck, I don't know how to, for each result, update `documents.created` with a substring of `k.keyword`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution, it creates the malformed data, then fixes it:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
 id int(11),
 created timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
2
INSERT INTO documents SET id = 1, created = 0;
INSERT INTO documents SET id = 2, created = 0;

CREATE TABLE keywords (
  document_id int(11),
  name varchar(128),
  value varchar(128)
);


INSERT INTO keywords SET document_id = 1, name = 'date', value = '2013-01-01 11:00:00';
INSERT INTO keywords SET document_id = 2, name = 'date', value = NOW();

UPDATE documents,
(
SELECT document_id, value
FROM keywords
WHERE name = 'date') AS subtable
SET created = subtable.value
WHERE documents.id = subtable.document_id
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching in docs I ended up with this, that doesn't make a subquery and works:

```
UPDATE documents d, keywords k
SET d.created = concat( substr(k.value,1,4), '-', substr(k.value,9,2), '-', substr(k.value,6,2) )
WHERE k.keyword = 'Fecha' AND k.document_id = d.id;
```